Is a victim's testimony alone sufficient evidence to support a felony conviction?
If, for example, a woman accuses a man of harassing her, can the man be convicted of a felony and sent to prison solely on the basis of the victim's testimony as the sole witness in the case without any other evidence?

What does "her sole witness is evidence" mean? That there was one witness corroborating the accusation? If you mean that there is no evidence, apart from her accusation, then no. Otherwise anyone could get anyone else jailed just by making an accusation which might not be true.

@WeatherVane Where does that rule exist? In the United States, at least,  people are charged, convicted, jailed based on a single accusation every day.

@WeatherVane: It is for the jury to decide whether the accusation is true.

I mean can person A say person X did crime Y to me and thus that is a piece of evidence and person X goes to prison afterwards

@AhmedHaniMosaad And the defendent can say "No, I didn't." Now it's up to the jury to decide which one is telling the truth.

that means that any accuser must provide witness other than himself(or a piece of physical evidence), am i getting it right ?

@AhmedHaniMosaad The closer issue in U.S. law is whether someone can be convicted of a crime based solely upon their own confession without any corroborating evidence that the crime ever happened. This isn't allowed in military courts in the U.S. and in some U.S. federal court circuits and some U.S. states, but is allowed in other U.S. federal court circuits and in some U.S. states.

@AhmedHaniMosaad They don't have to. But the more corroborating evidence they can provide, the more likely they are to be believed. Meanwhile, the accused can provide evidence against your claims (such as an alibi), or they can try to impeach your testimony (this is what Trump's lawyers have been doing in the hush money trial).

Forgive me if I am making stereotypical assumptions based upon your name, but, of course, corroboration requirements for certain kinds of allegations of wrongful conduct are one of the important ways in which the Islamic law legal system differs from the common law legal system. See https://www.ojp.gov/ncjrs/virtual-library/abstracts/means-evidence-islamic-law-effect-islamic-legislation-saudi-arabia The systems have different kinds of safeguards in place to avoid wrongful convictions in the overall process. Explaining why the systems developed differently would be a long essay.

@Barmar only in a common law country. In an inquisitorial civil law country, you don't get to ask questions until the judge has had its turn.

@Trish But they still get their chance, just in a different order?

Many cases of actual innocence have involved people convicted based on the testimony of a single witness and no corroborating physical evidence.

united-states
Yes, someone can be convicted of a felony based solely upon that testimony of a single witness, who may be the victim of the crime. See, e.g., Williams v. Florida (Fla. App. 2018).
Similarly, a criminal defense lawyer in Texas states clearly that "the testimony of one witness is enough evidence to convict a person of a crime in Texas. Provided that the testimony is convincing, a person can be found guilty of a crime and go to prison based on the testimony of a single witness."
California Evidence Code § 411 says so clearly, expressly disavowing any legal requirement that witness testimony be corroborated by other evidence:

Except where additional evidence is required by statute, the direct
evidence of one witness who is entitled to full credit is sufficient
for proof of any fact.

No corroborating evidence is legally required. Indeed, convictions of crimes solely on the testimony of a single witness aren't even terribly uncommon.
Sworn witness testimony subject to cross-examination is evidence just like any other evidence. See, e.g., Colorado Criminal Jury Instructions (2022) D01 (Direct v. Circumstantial Evidence), E03 (Reasonable Doubt), E04 (Number of Witnesses), and E05 (Credibility of Witnesses). See also, e.g., United States v. Kenyon, 481 F.3d 1054 (8th Cir. 2007) (where victim testified that the defendant placed his penis in the victim’s mouth at least once, this was sufficient to convict the defendant on one count of child sexual abuse).
If the finder of fact (a jury in most cases, but a judge in a bench trial) concludes that this testimony is sufficient to prove the prosecution's case beyond a reasonable doubt, then the conviction is valid. Convictions will only be overturned on appeal if there is not evidence in the trial court record to support them, viewing all evidence received in the light most favorable to the jury's verdict.

In reviewing a record for sufficiency, the relevant inquiry is
whether, after viewing the evidence in a light most favorable to the
prosecution, any rational trier of fact could have found the essential
elements of the crime proven beyond a reasonable doubt.

State v. Conway, 108 Ohio St. 3d 214, 2006-Ohio-791, ¶36.

In deciding whether the evidence presented at a trial was sufficient to
support a criminal conviction, a court must “determine whether such
evidence, if believed, would convince the average mind of the
defendant’s guilt beyond a reasonable doubt.”

State v. Troisi, 124 Ohio St. 3d 404, 2010-Ohio-275, ¶7.

When reviewing the sufficiency of the evidence, this Court must review
the evidence in a light most favorable to the prosecution to determine
whether the evidence before the trial court was sufficient to sustain
a conviction.  State v. Jenks, 61 Ohio St.3d 259, 279 (1991).

State v. Howse, 2024-Ohio-503.
The evidence is viewed in the light most favorable to the prosecution, and a reviewing court will not infringe upon the province of the jury by reweighing the evidence. In re Washington, 81 Ohio St. 3d 337, 339 (1998).

does that mean that i can for instance say after swearing oath "person A robbed me and that is my testimony" and person A goes to prison afterwards

i was just asking out of curiosity guys i know that there is nothing as a person using himself as witness for himself because that will basically give any body the ability to imprison any body they want

@AhmedHaniMosaad "can for instance say after swearing oath "person A robbed me and that is my testimony" and person A goes to prison afterwards" Basically, yes. The statement would have to be somewhat more detailed than that, because the testimony would have to include the underlying facts of what happened sufficient to show that the elements of robbery had taken place and not just the legal conclusion that there was a robbery (e.g. Andy pointed a gun at me and said "your money or your life" and I gave him my money and then Andy left.).

@AhmedHaniMosaad "i was just asking out of curiosity guys i know that there is nothing as a person using himself as witness for himself because that will basically give any body the ability to imprison any body they want" Keep in mind that criminal prosecutions have to be filed by the prosecutor's office, that some states require a grand jury to approve felony charges, and that the jury has to believe the witness in the face of cross-examination by the defendant's lawyer and any evidence offered by the defendant's lawyer. Courts routinely resolve cases by deciding who is lying and who is not.

@AhmedHaniMosaad you can say whatever you want, but you have to convince the jury to believe you. If you have no additional details (time, what the robber was wearing, where you were at the time, what he stole, etc) then your statement isn't very believable. The same if your statements are inconsistent, or the accused has some evidence that they were somewhere else at the time, etc. Not everything you say will automatically be believed.

@Tak after seeing a lot of your comments across the site, I wish to remind you of how comments are to be used.

The law of scotland has historically taken the position that "no one shall in any case be convicted on the testimony of a single witness. No matter how trivial the offence, and how high so ever the credit and character of the witness, still our law is averse to rely on his single word." (Hume, Commentaries on the Law of Scotland regarding Crimes, vol. 2, p383). The rule is said to derive from such Biblical foundations as Deuteronomy 19:15,

One witness shall not rise up against a man for any iniquity, or for any sin, in any sin that he sinneth: at the mouth of two witnesses, or at the mouth of three witnesses, shall the matter be established. (KJV)

However, this requirement for corroboration is subtle and does not mean that two or more witnesses are always required to prove every single element of an offence. The modern position is set out in a recent en banc judgment, Reference by HM Advocate against CLB [2023] HCJAC 40. At paragraph 235:

The basic rule is that no-one can be convicted on the testimony of one witness alone. Where there is direct (eye witness) evidence of the crime, that evidence can be corroborated by another eye witness or by facts and circumstances spoken to by at least one other witness. None of these individual facts and circumstances needs to be spoken to by more than one
witness, and the offence to which the witness speaks need not be divided into several
constituent parts. That applies equally in a wholly circumstantial case. Where there is one
eye witness, the facts and circumstances spoken to by one or more other witnesses are
corroborative if they confirm or support the eye witness evidence of the crime. They do not
themselves, looked at in isolation, require to point towards the commission of the crime as if
they were the equivalent of a second eye witness. If they did that, they would, without the
existence of the direct testimony, be sufficient as a wholly circumstantial case, provided that
there was more than one witness in the case. What requires to be proved by corroborated
evidence is the case against the accused. That is, first, that the crime, which is libelled, was
committed and secondly, that it was the accused who committed it. There is no requirement
to prove the separate elements in a crime by corroborated evidence.

In particular, a victim of a rape which takes place in private will not have a second eyewitness to the event. But not every single point of her testimony needs to be separately corroborated. It can be enough to present other evidence which backs up her account, such as that somebody else saw her in distress at the time, or that she told someone what happened soon afterwards (a "de recenti statement"). Physical evidence, if available, can also be corroborative. Indeed, this sort of overlapping evidence can have more overall probative value than having two people testify to the exact same thing.
There are also several statutory and common-law exceptions to the rule, in particular circumstances or for certain offences.
In any given trial, it's up to the judge to direct the jury (or himself if there is no jury) as to what sort of corroboration is required at law. Whoever is the finder of fact must then assess whether the evidence presented, taken together, meets the required standard of proof.

Don't forget other, physical circumstantial evidence, such as a sperm sample or destroyed clothing.

@Trish, thanks, I added a brief mention of physical evidence

canada
The question always remains whether the finder of fact is convinced beyond a reasonable doubt as to the guilt of the accused.
See R. v. (W.)(D.), [1991] 1 SCR 742:

First, if you believe the evidence of the accused, obviously you must acquit.
Second, if you do not believe the testimony of the accused but you are left in reasonable doubt by it, you must acquit.
Third, even if you are not left in doubt by the evidence of the accused, you must ask yourself whether, on the basis of the evidence which you do accept, you are convinced beyond a reasonable doubt by that evidence of the guilt of the accused.

Convictions can successfully be obtained based on the sole testimony of a credible and reliable complainant.
There are other related question on this site:

How is a judge to evaluate a witness's credibility?
How do you prove a fact at issue in litigation?


The quoted text is about the evidence of the accused, while OP is asking about evidence of the accuser.

I see.  But it's kind of confusing when you quote three points, of which the first two are irrelevant to the question.

Does that mean that i can accuse any body of a crime and they will go to prison afterwards on the basis that my accusation is a piece of evidence ?

@AhmedHaniMosaad If your accusation is credible, and there's no evidence to the contrary, what else should the judge/jury conclude?

If you claimed that I punched you in the face and broke two teeth, you would have a bruised face and two broken teeth as evidence. Without them no conviction. Next the defense lawyer will claim the offender might be just someone looking like me, and you’d have to convince the jury otherwise. Next you might have a history of making accusations, or the accusation comes just after I got a promotion that you wanted. And the jury might doubt your testimony.

germany
A Victim is someone that was present and the target of some act, so they are also a witness.
Witnesses present evidence to the judge[s], their statement is evidence and follows the rules under StPO (for crimes) and ZPO (for civil cases).
The credibility of witness statements is weighed only by the judge[s], and most questions come from the judge's bench - the witness has to be truthful. Only after the judge[s] had their turn, the other parties may ask questions. Questions regarding credibility need to suffice §68a StPO or §395 ZPO.
If a single witness is deemed credible and the breach of law is proven by this statement beyond a reasonable doubt, then the court will rule accordingly.
In a case of one witness only, typically you see a "He said-she said" situation of the witness' statement versus the accused's statement. The court will weigh both their credibilities against one another and create a legal fiction of what transpired.
